# Twilio StatusCallback - Post Method implementation

Tags: twilio

There is a requirement to integrate SF with Twilio for sending messages on mobile,which i was able to achieve.
I would like to track the status of the sent message using the parameter:
'&StatusCallback=  EncodingUtil.urlEncode('
https://cs5.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Postback');

What should the method of the REST webservices have in its POST method?
If Twilio is posting back the status, then what should the POST method of the webservices do? Not able to get a idea on this, please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a class doing that update using the callback URL:
https://github.com/britishboyindc/TextToCase_Twilio_Salesforce/blob/master/src/classes/smsResponse.cls

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/smsResponse')
global class smsResponse {

    @HttpPost
    global static void incomingSMSResponse() {

        String expectedSignature = RestContext.request.headers.get('X-Twilio-Signature');
        String url = 'https://' + RestContext.request.headers.get('Host') + '/services/apexrest' + RestContext.request.requestURI;
        Map <String, String> params = RestContext.request.params;
        system.debug('Return Response' + params);

       // Validate signature

        if (!TwilioAPI.getDefaultClient().validateRequest(expectedSignature, url, params)) {
            RestContext.response.statusCode = 403;
            RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Failure! Rcvd '+expectedSignature+'\nURL '+url+'\nHeaders'+RestContext.request.headers);
            return;
        }

        SMS_Message_Tracking__c smstrack = new SMS_Message_Tracking__c();
        smstrack.SID__c = params.get('SmsSid');
        smstrack.Status__c = params.get('SmsStatus');
        upsert smstrack SID__c;

     }
}
```

Comment: I am extremely thankful to you BritishBoyinDC!It worked like a charm!

Comment: that works perfect, but for some reason in the debug of twilio console i get a warning: Error - 11200 it seems for me twilio expects soemthing after they do the API in the endpoint?

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC, I've almost created same kind of Rest Service and didn't even get in to this class after successful first send sms request, then I refer this and modified my Post method but still didn't get into the post method. Do we need to setup anything in Twilio site or in SF like public site to reach the Twilio response to the post method? I am developing and testing this in a scratch org.

Comment: @Hariprasath So yes - if it is an non authenticated REST endpoint, you need to setup a public site, and then expose this apex class on the site, which you can then use as the webhook endpoint in Twilio. But worth noting SF has changed the security behind sites recently, so you'd need this class to run without sharing to ensure it keeps working

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC Tried this option as well but still the callback is not receiving anything from Twilio. Dead end seems to me. Any other suggestions/ steps that I miss? May be error in the callback URL, I am passing https://customer-ruby-2433-dev-ed.cs76.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/smsResponse as StatusCallback

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC got a debug from twilio said [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}] and in the SF log I am getting empty map for params. I am not sure how can I pass the session Id to send response to SF by Twilio.

Comment: That URL looks wrong - a public site should look more like this:
https://[mysitedomain].secure.force.com/services/apexrest/smsResponse
In setup, you go to sites, click on the Site and you'll see the public domain there. That's where you set the public access for the class

Comment: yes my bad. Thanks @BritishBoyinDC. got the below error in Twillio site error. Failure! Rcvd null
URL XXXX
Headers{Accept=*/*, Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br, CipherSuite=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 443, Connection=keep-alive, Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, Host=sandbox-customer-ruby-2433-dev-ed-176e2b0aef4.cs76.force.com, Postman-Token=b07b9d38-2d93-4ffa-bc4c-35a169c33c46, User-Agent=PostmanRuntime/7.26.8, X-Salesforce-Forwarded-To=cs76.salesforce.com, X-Salesforce-SIP=112.134.191.71,

Comment: Finally could able to test the whole flow by removing the signature validation part in the Post method. But need to figure it out to validate the signature. Thanks for the whole support @BritishBoyinDC.

Answer (score 1):

Please find this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554138/how-to-make-sure-a-sms-went-through-after-sending-it-with-twilio) with a detailed explanation. Hope this helps.

If you specify a `StatusCallback` URL when you make the request to send an SMS, Twilio will make a request to the callback URL you provided after the message has finished processing, with the parameters either `SmsStatus=sent` or `SmsStatus=failed`. You can use this information to do more processing on the SMS message. There's more information here: `http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms#post-parameters-optional`

Alternately, if you hang on to the SMS Message Sid, you should be able to query the API for the message and get the status in the response. So if the sid is SM123, making a GET request to `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC123/SMS/Messages/SM123.json` should return a object with the status of the SMS Message.