# how to track the status of twilio sms status in custom object with status as sent in salesforce?

Tags: apex, twilio

how to track the status of twilio sms status in custom object with status as sent in salesforce? (using Rest api).
The records gets created, but the fields are null. I am new to integration; please suggest some solutions.

```
@RestResource(urlmapping='/SMSMessageTrackings/')
global class smsResponse {

    @HttpPost
    global static void incomingSMSResponse(){

        RestRequest requ = new RestRequest();  
        RestResponse resp = new RestResponse();
        RestContext.request = requ;     
        RestContext.response = resp;
        Map <String, String> params = RestContext.request.params;
        system.debug('Return Response' + params);


        SMS_Message_Tracking__c smstrack = new SMS_Message_Tracking__c();
        smstrack.SID__c = params.get('SmsSid');
        smstrack.Status__c = params.get('SmsStatus');
        upsert smstrack;
        system.debug('inserting data'+ smstrack );
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour], and read [ask]. I've not used Twilio myself, but this is probably something you can find if you read the Twilio documentation. Questions here tend to be better received by the community if you include plenty of detail, show that you have tried to research your problem and tried solve it by yourself first, include code (where appropriate), and be specific about where exactly you're stuck. You can add these extra details to your question by making an [edit] (comments are best through of as temporary, so adding information via an edit is preferred)

Comment: When you look at your logs, what do you see for the debug statements?

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting all the incoming data on your REST request.

```
    RestRequest requ = new RestRequest();  
    RestResponse resp = new RestResponse();
    RestContext.request = requ;     
    RestContext.response = resp;
    Map <String, String> params = RestContext.request.params;
```

This doesn't make sense. You should not assign new, empty instances to `RestContext.request` and `RestContext.response`. Now `RestContext.request.params` refers to a completely empty map, and you've lost the original request data.

Remove those assignments and check your debug statements to confirm you're receiving the data you epect.

Comment: I get this exception in the debug log,System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object.

Comment: That is almost certainly because of the issue above.

Comment: i referred this link :https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96317/twilio-statuscallback-post-method-implementation

Comment: That class doesn't include the problem in yours as described in this answer. I expect that one works.

Comment: In that class expectedSignature ,url ,Return Response,smstrack  are returning null

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you here. I don't know the class you linked. Your class is clearly broken for the reasons outlined above.

Comment: I am using twilio to send sms ,after i send a sms i get the status as queued ,but i expect the status to be sent/failed.I am implementing a rest class to make the request and get the response.Any suggestions would help me,sorry for my ignorance.